# Android IAB Purchases not visible when query inventory called on device with newer android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have an IAB setup where there is only one item to buy - Full version unlocker.

If i purchase an item on SG4 and then open the app on SEM - the item is found in the inventory and a license is also accepted on SEM - so far so good.

But if i do this the other way around - the purchase from SEM is not visible when inventory is queried with SG4

Any clue why?

Devices

- SG4 - Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini - GT-i9195 (stock Jelly Bean MR1 4.2.2)
- SEM - Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro - SK17i (stock Gingerbread MR1 2.3.4)

Notes:

- If i try to purchase the item again i get the "Item already owned message"
- I'm using the exact same apk on both devices
- I started from the Trivia tutorial - there are no significant changes in the code
- I have an apk published in alfa & beta version (since 2wks ago) with the same version number as on device but the app is not public yet.
- I use the same testing account as primary account on both devices - but not the same as developer account where the apk is published
- Im using IabHelper
- I tested using android.test.purchased and my own SKU - the resulta are the same

Comment: I am facing a similar situation where I purchased android.test.purchased product on one device with x as a primary account but when i queried the purchased items from another device with same x as primary account i am getting null result. If you find  a problem let me know it will be helpful to me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only with real purchases.